# Daily Sync Job in SQL server refreshes everyday

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssms

I have SSIS package (objects used ADO. net source and destination. No other logic in the data flow) which copies tables from server A to server B. And the that packages are refreshed daily. Does it mean my records get duplicated everyday in server B?

Lift and Shift from server A to B but not expecting to create duplicates everyday

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you say, "No other logic in the data flow" Therefore, the source will pull all the data you have specified - likely a table. The target will receive all of those rows unless you have a primary or unique constraint on the table in which case, by default you will receive zero rows as the default is to commit as the entire batch.

Not asked but this also means you will not receive any updates to rows in the source table. For things like write-only data (sensor/log data), that's probably fine. Other source systems, less so.

How do you keep the two servers in sync - "It depends" [TM] but generally you want to look at something like an "SSIS incremental load pattern." Many search results from those 4 words but I like the Stairway to Integration Services series by Andy Leonard, specifically you're looking at steps [3](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/adding-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-3-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services) and [4](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/updating-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-4-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services)